# Toiling with HTMLEditorKit

Tags: java, swing, dom, htmleditorkit

Im a novice Java programmer trying to use the HTMLEditorKit library to traverse a HTML document and alter it to my linking (mostly for the fun of it, what I'm doing could be done in hand without a problem)

But my problem is: After i have modifed my HTML file i am left with a HTMLDocument that i have no clue how to save back to a HTML file.

```
HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
File file = new File("local file")
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) kit.createDefaultDocument(); 
doc.putProperty("IgnoreCharsetDirective", Boolean.TRUE);
InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()); 
FileReader HTMLReader = new FileReader(file); 
kit.read(HTMLReader, doc, 0);
```

after that i do my thing with the "doc" element.

Now that im done with that i just want to save it back, preferablly overwriting the file which i got HTML from in the first place.

Anyone able to tell me how to save the modified HTMLdocument into a html file afterwards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [write method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html#write%28java.io.Writer,%20javax.swing.text.Document,%20int,%20int%29) of HTMLEditorKit class. Sample code here:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("local file");
try {
  kit.write(writer, doc, 0, doc.getLength());
} finally {
  writer.close();
}
```